# Salesforce Scheduler Appointment Page Not Showing Operating Hours Time Slot

Tags: lightning-scheduler

I am facing an issue related to the Salesforce Scheduler. I have created records for everything like territory, service resource, work types, workgroups, operating hours, time-slots but when I am scheduling appointment through quick action, in the timeslot section, I am not seeing any timeslots. This is the problem which I am facing in Salesforce Scheduler and I am not able to figure out the cause.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`ResourceType` field on `Service Resource` object should be either set to `'Technician'` or `'Asset'` without which time slots wouldn't appear on the calendar.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_salesforce_scheduler_object_fields_service_resource.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

When you create a permission set Salesforce Scheduler resource as mentioned in the document, under system permissions enable 'Let a user be included in appointment in Salesforce Scheduler'. It did not help me. But see if that helps your particular case. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_manage_perms.htm&type=5

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? With which user are you trying to schedule an appointment? And have you assigned this permission set to that user?

Answer (score -1):

Did you figure out, I am on the same page where time slots do not show up despite creating all records like service resource, service territory, hours, shifts, wt, wtg

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE).  Please see the notes about "me too!" responses and "asking another, different question" in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will most likely be deleted.  Please contribute to SFSE in other ways so that you gain reputation - you only need 15 rep to upvote a question and only 50 rep to comment under someone else's question. You can also "Follow" (look at bottom left of every post) a question or answer to be notified when it is updated.

Comment: It was a permission issue. I have not assigned the salesforce scheduler permission set to the. After assigning that to the user I was able to see the time slots. Please check that.

Comment: @DeepanshuRajta : If I understand this comment of yours, you figured out your own solution.  It is perfectly acceptable (in fact, it is encouraged) to answer your own question.  So if you have found your own solution, please add it as an answer and not a comment, so it will be more easily seen and therefore helpful to future seekers.